# How to best implement a class method that is different for every object of this class

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

As a teacher I want to code a worksheet-generator for mathematical problems.
Python should generate mathematical problems and their solution (e.g. create a polynomial function and calculate their zeros). It then writes a LaTeX input file and creates a pdf via `pdflatex`. It works for several problems, but now I want to generalize it and make it object-orientated to speed up the creation of further worksheets.

So I created a class `Problem` with several parameters and methods. But every `Problem`-instance should have a different function for creating the text for the mathematical problem and its solution (because every object is a different mathematical problem). And I've got no clue how I should manage this in an elegant/proper way.

At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
import random


class Problem_generator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.problemlist = []

    def create_worksheet(self):
        """ Creates the latex-document by writing the output in a LaTeX input file. For 
            this minimal example, I'll just print the outputs instead.
        """
        for problem in self.problemlist:
            text = problem.create()
            print("Problem: " + text[0])
            print("Solution: " + text[1])


class Problem(object):
    def __init__(self, problem_generator, function):
        # do some stuff like to create Tkinter-GUI-objects for every problem
        self.function = function
        problem_generator.problemlist.append(self)

    def create(self):
        return self.function()


def add_numbers():
    """ Create the problem to add two numbers. """

    a, b = random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)
    problem_text = str(a) + " + " + str(b)
    solution_text = str(a+b)
    return problem_text, solution_text


generator = Problem_generator()
problem_1 = Problem(generator, add_numbers)

generator.create_worksheet()  # in the complete program I start this over a GUI
```

It works alright, but it doesn't feel "right".
I also thought about implementing the `Problem` class with a `create()` method that only raises a not-implemented-error and then to update the `create()` method for every problem I create. But as far as I read, that would update the `create()` method for every object of the class.

So I would be happy to get some tips/suggestions how I could manage the described problem in an "elegant" way.

Comment: Generally speaking, the classic OOP way to do handle such a scenario is to define an abstract base class with the overall interface and perhaps some generic helper methods and then define problem-specific "concrete" subclasses that implement the methods that do the problem-specific things. Basically like what @tchar illustrates in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68795613/355230).

Comment: Ok, so you would suggest the to do it this way? Or is there another/better approach?
Let's say in general, this program don't have to be perfect, I'm just a autodidact/hobby-coder. But I'm just curious to learn a bit more about programming and learn a somehow good/clean style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already said in a comment, the classic [object-oriented programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) way to do handle such a scenario is to define an abstract base class with the overall interface and perhaps some generic helper methods and then define problem-specific "concrete" subclasses. Here's a toy example of doing something like that on Python it with based on the code in your question. If it seems like you're creating a bunch of almost-the-same classes. Sometimes the remedy for that is to subclass your subclasses, but often it just means you haven't abstracted the problem well…

From the comments in your sample code, it sounds like you also want have your classes be responsible for creating their own tkinter objects for a graphical user interface (GUI). Generally speaking that's probably not a good idea — classes should generally only have a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), which mean trying pile many of them on can greatly complicate matters by make testing, debugging, and extending what you have a lot more difficult.

There's a commonly used software design pattern called [model–view–controller (MVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) that is commonly used for developing user interfaces that a program up into three interconnected components, but keeps each one separate to reduce complexity — so I suggest you invest a the time studying it.

```
import abc
import random


class Problem(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """ Abstract base class of all mathematical problems. """

    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def create_problem(self):
        """ Creates input to be fed to the create_worksheet method. """
        ...

    def create_worksheet(self, indent=4, char=' '):
        """ Creates the latex-document by writing the output in a LaTeX input file.
            In this toy example, it just print the lines the create_problem() method
            generated.
        """
        padding = indent * char
        for line in self.lines:
            print(padding + line)


class AddNumbers(Problem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Initialize base class.
        self.create_problem()  # Create subclass-specific data.

    def create_problem(self):
        a, b = random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)
        self.lines.append(f'Problem: Add the two numbers {a} and {b} together')
        self.lines.append(f'Solution: {a+b}')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create some sample Problem subclass instances.
    problems = [AddNumbers(), AddNumbers()]

    # Create worksheet the worksheet for each one.
    for i, problem in enumerate(problems, start=1):
        print(f'Worksheet {i}:')
        problem.create_worksheet(indent=2)
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tips. I'll have a look at the MVC-Concept for further projects.
One further question: You're generating a new subclass for every Problem. What is the benefit of doing this instead of just creating objects of the before defined baseclass Problem?

Comment: If you're creating a bunch of almost-the-same classes,especially ones that only differ in what data they contain, then the abstraction is wrong. What you want to abstract is *behavior* i.e. implementation. If it's just data, there's no reason to create subclasses because you could simply pass different arguments when creating instance of a single class to deal with that. If you look around around for OOP examples, pay attention to how that is being split-up between the base and its subclasses.

Comment: So you would suggest to define the textgenerating functions as simple functions and to pass them as an argument to the calss problem?

Comment: Yes, you could do things that way and it might be the best way to do them if there aren't any other differences between instances of the class and the generation of the text doesn't depend on them — in which case, why not just pass the generated text in as an argument instead of a callable to do it? What's the advantage of postponing it?

Comment: I also thought of this, but so far as I used this, I implemented for the problem-class an option to be selected/deslected, an option how many times this problem should be created and an option to mix all or a subset of selected problems. So that I can e.g. create an worksheet with 2x multiply and 4x addtion-problems, but no substraction and mix them all together. Furthermore I implemented an option to create more than one worksheet. All in all I think this can be realised better if the text will be generated as an method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I'd do it:

```
import random
from typing import Callable, List, Tuple


ProblemCreator = Callable[[], Tuple[str, str]]  # returns (problem, solution)


class Problem:
    def __init__(self, function: ProblemCreator) -> None:
        # do some stuff like to create Tkinter-GUI-objects for every problem
        self.create = function


class ProblemGenerator:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.problem_list: List[Problem] = []

    def create_worksheet(self) -> None:
        """
        Creates the latex-document by writing the output in a *.tex-file.
        For this minimal example, I'll just print the outputs instead.
        """
        for problem in self.problem_list:
            p, s = problem.create()
            print(f"Problem: {p}")
            print(f"Solution: {s}")

    def generate_problem(self, problem: ProblemCreator) -> None:
        self.problem_list.append(Problem(problem))


def add_numbers() -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """  Create the problem to add two numbers. """
    a, b = random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)
    return f"{a} + {b}", f"{a+b}"


generator = ProblemGenerator()
generator.generate_problem(add_numbers)

generator.create_worksheet()  # in the complete program I start this over a GUI
```

I've used type annotations and other Python 3 features (like f-strings) to improve clarity.

There is no need for `create` to be a method -- just make it a callable attribute (I've given the type of this callable a name, `ProblemCreator`, since it forms an important part of this interface).  Similarly, there's no need for `Problem` to know about `ProblemGenerator` and be responsible for adding itself to the generator's list; it just creates a circular dependency that you don't need.  Instead, have `ProblemGenerator` be in charge of generating problems (like its name says)!

Comment: Hey Samwise,
Thanks for your tips! To let the generator form the problems seems to be a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't find any use for the Problem_generator class, here is how I would do it (I added a ProblemGenerator class but you can loop and call problem.create)

By using this you can

- define problems as a subclass of Problem (see AddTwoNumbers class)
- define problems as functions (see subtract_numbers function) and use the problem_decorator to convert them to FunctionProblems (subclass of Problem).

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from functools import wraps
import random
from typing import Callable, List, Tuple

random.seed(0) # for reproducability

class Problem(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def text(self) -> str:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def solution_text(self) -> str:
        pass


class AddTwoNumbers(Problem):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._a = random.randint(0, 100)
        self._b = random.randint(0, 100)

    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return f'{self._a} + {self._b}'

    @property
    def solution_text(self) -> str:
        return str(self._a + self._b)

# If you want to define functions as problems you can do something like that
class FunctionProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[], Tuple[str, str]]):
        self._text, self._solution_text = func()

    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return self._text

    @property
    def solution_text(self) -> str:
        return self._solution_text

# Define a decorator so that functions become FunctionProblems
def problem_decorator(func: Callable[[], Tuple[str, str]]) -> Callable[[], FunctionProblem]:
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        return FunctionProblem(func)
    return wrapper

@problem_decorator
def subtract_numbers() -> Tuple[str, str]:
    a, b = random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)
    text = f'{a} - {b}'
    solution = str(a - b)
    return text, solution

# If you really want to define a ProblemGenerator
class ProblemGenerator:
    def __init__(self, *problems: Problem) -> None:
        self.problems = list(problems)

    def add_problem(self, problem: Problem) -> None:
        self.problems.append(problem)

    def create_worksheet(self) -> List[Tuple[str, str]]:
        for problem in self.problems:
            print(f'Problem text is {problem.text!r}, Solution is {problem.solution_text!r}')

generator = ProblemGenerator(AddTwoNumbers())
generator.add_problem(subtract_numbers())
generator.create_worksheet()
```

prints

```
Problem text is '49 + 97', Solution is '146'
Problem text is '53 - 5', Solution is '48'
```

Comment: Hey tchar,
Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not quite sure - is it useful to make a subclass for every problem when I just need one object of this subclass?
The problem_generator should at one hand form a kind of wrapper. So that I can loop over all defined problems. On the other hand I bound the main-GUI-window (and its buttons etc) at the problem-generator. I don't need to do it this way, but it seemed reasonable to me.

Comment: Depends on how much flexibility you want. You can use the method definition of a Problem, but classes give you more flexibility. Not sure about the context you are using it but this is how I would write it to be enxtensible.

Comment: The main issue here is not what looks good or not, defining a class Problem just to pass a function to be called, is not the best design you can pass the function directly to the problem generator and call it instead if the only thing you want is to call it. Problem.create instead of calling the function makes no difference if you only use the class in this way.

Comment: Ah ok. So far as I used this, I implemented for the problem-class an option to be selected/deslected, an option how many times this problem should be created and an option to mix all or a subset of selected problems. So that I can e.g. create an worksheet with 2x multiply and 4x addtion-problems, but no substraction and mix all together. Furthermore I created the option to input the range for a problem via GUI (e.g. use numbers between 100 and 1000). I bound all this and the GUI-elements to display/get this options to the Problem-class.

Comment: As far as I think, the above described options should suffice, but if I want to implement other options later, it could maybe better to generalize more (I'm not quite sure about that, because I've just made some smaller problems so far)

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense.